# Howto chain objects in PHP5: $this->foo->bar->baz()

Tags: php, class, oop, chaining

How do I make chained objects in PHP5 classes? Examples:

```
$myclass->foo->bar->baz();
$this->foo->bar->baz();
Not: $myclass->foo()->bar()->baz();
```

See also:
http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html

Comment: remember you are able change your accepted answer :P

Comment: Gabriel Sosa is right. Chaining should be done through the methods return value (i.e. return $this;) and using $this->method1()->method2() rather than assigning an object to properties and using $this->obj1->obj2, which is unnecessary in most cases and can cause confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as your $myclass has a member/property that is an instance itself it will work just like that.

```
class foo {
   public $bar;
}

class bar {
    public function hello() {
       return "hello world";
    }
}

$myclass = new foo();
$myclass->bar = new bar();
print $myclass->bar->hello();
```

Comment: Anti Veeranna's solution fits my purpose - to make readable, self-documenting code (when methods are called across classes).

Answer (score 7):

actually this questions is ambiguous.... for me this @Geo's answer is right one.

What you (@Anti) says could be [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)

This is my example for this:

```
<?php
class Greeting {
    private $what;
    private $who;


    public function say($what) {
        $this->what = $what;
        return $this;
    }

    public function to($who) {
        $this->who = $who;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return sprintf("%s %s\n", $this->what, $this->who);
    }

}

$greeting = new Greeting();
echo $greeting->say('hola')->to('gabriel'); // will print: hola gabriel
```

?>

Comment: Might I also add that this is a very elegant way of coding.

Comment: Very interesting coding. One caveat seems to be that it doesn't "document" method calls across classes - as in $url->anchor(). Still, I'm sure I will find a use for this coding style some day. Thanks.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In order to chain function calls like that, usually you return self ( or this ) from the function.

Comment: The question is confusing, but I think this is exactly what he does NOT want to do :)

Comment: Exactly. The purpose is to "self-document" calls to methods in other classes. Good: $url->anchor(). Bad: $this->anchor(). :-)