# slick way to assign variable back

Tags: php, php-5.4

Currently I am doing this

```
$product = myProductCalss::myproduct($id);
$product = $product->myproduct;
```

is there another slick way to do this so that I can kinda do it in one liner?

Comment: Use chaining. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385429/howto-chain-objects-in-php5-this-foo-bar-baz

Comment: `$product = myProductCalss::myproduct($id); $product = $product->myproduct;` Remove the line break, now it's one line :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis should work:

```
$product = myProductCalss::myproduct($id)->myproduct;
```

Your question doesn`t belong here, check https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php