# "chaining" a class to a main class

Tags: php, design-patterns, php-5.4

I couldn't think of the way to describer what I want to do, but I've seen several libraries and frameworks do it and I'm trying to figure it out for something I'm working on.

I'm working on an API client that has multiple classes. I have a main class that will contain all the OAuth stuff. I'd like the person using my API Client to be able to do something like so:

```
$api = baseAPI();

$user = $api->user->getUserProfile('user');

echo $user->Nickname;
```

user would be a class that has several methods. One could see an Admin object being accessible and a login object.

I hope I delivered my question well enough that someone understands what I'm trying to accomplish. I could try to explain it better if I did not.

Much appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but based on your description I think you're trying to extend a class. If this is what you're trying to do, there are plenty of helpful articles on extending classes!

Here's a pretty decent example: [Chaining classes](https://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/php-tutorial-learning-oop-class-basics-extending-classes/)

There are also plenty of examples here on SO.

Hope this helped!

Comment: the idea is the user would just use one class to access the other classes in the library. I suppose I could try creating a base class that each object reference.

Comment: sleeping on it seems to help with searching SO. I found a few articles that perfectly describe what I want to do.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385429/howto-chain-objects-in-php5-this-foo-bar-baz